# JavaScript RegExp to remove @ sign from starting position

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

**`I want modify my regular expression to also remove @ size but select only that word those are start with @ sign.`**

Following is my code, View <kbd>**[Live](http://regex101.com/r/zF5eC4/1)**</kbd>

### JS

```
var a = "@abc @jat hi pat @jkl abc  @cde vcd @cde   ";
var s = a.match(/(?=(\s{1}?@[^\s]+)|(\s?))(@[^\s]+)(?=(\s))/g);

console.log(s);
```

### Result

```
["@abc", "@jat", "@jkl", "@cde", "@cde"]
```

### Expected Result

```
["abc", "jat", "jkl", "cde", "cde"]
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JavaScript doesn't have look-behind, I don't think you can do it in a single `match` statement (without post-processing), because you'll want a capture group.

The post-processing is trivial with ES5's `Array#map` (which can be shimmed), of course:

```
var s = a.match(/(?=(\s{1}?@[^\s]+)|(\s?))(@[^\s]+)(?=(\s))/g).map(function(entry) {
    return entry.substring(1);
});
```

Otherwise, you'll want to use a capture group and an `exec` loop.

BTW, I think the regular expression can be a lot simpler, if all you want is `\s` separation:

```js
var a = "@abc @jat hi pat @jkl abc  @cde vcd @cde   ";
var s = a.match(/@\S+/g).map(function(entry) {
    return entry.substring(1);
});
display(s.join(", "));

function display(msg) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<p>" + msg + "</p>"
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i'm not access other fuction (like map) to archive this. Can you modify my regexp pattern to archive this. thanks

Comment: @user1153551: No, I can't. And I suspect no one else can either, for the reason I gave above (JavaScript doesn't have look-behind).

Comment: I m not sure but may be Python RegExp have this select negotation. And JS does not have surprising

Comment: @user1153551: Different flavors of regex in different languages have different capabilities. This [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a pretty good resource because it discusses a lot of the differences.

Comment: Okay no problem i will done this way thank you Matt Burland and T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some compelling reason you need to write a single regexp for this, you're **much** better off just doing some standard splitting and filtering.

```
a.split(/\s+/)
    .filter(function(seg) { return seg[0]==='@'; })
    .map   (function(seg) { return seg.slice(1); })
```

It doesn't look so bad if you can use arrow functions:

```
a.split(/\s+/)
    .filter(seg => seg[0]==='@')
    .map   (seg => seg.slice(1))
```